# The Game of Life action cards that require a house but you don’t own one

Tags: game-of-life

We just bought the Game of Life 2021 version. I never landed on a house space to be able to buy one but my action cards I drew required me to pay for repairs. No where in the instructions for set up does it say you have to buy one. Also when you land on a house space it gives you the option to buy or do nothing. I tried taking pictures but was unable to upload.

Comment: What you do you mean about not being required to buy a house, all the rules I have seen state that it is required. "When you reach this space, stop -- even if you have moves left. Draw 1 House Deed at random from the deck. Pay the bank the price on the
deed (not the insurance amount; that ’s a separate transaction). If you ’re short on cash, you must borrow from the bank. Then spin and move again." https://www.hasbro.com/common/instruct/life.pdf

Comment: @JoeW why don't you turn that into an answer? You have all the information needed right there.

Comment: @Jungkook Because I don't fully understand what is being asked and I am looking for more details.

Comment: @JoeW Look at the copyright date on those instructions; I don't think it's the same in the 2021 version.

Comment: @DM That doesn't mean the rules are different.

Comment: @JoeW Unless they changed the rules a few times and then changed them *back* again, the rules are different.

Comment: @DM Unless we have a link to the rules for the version in question or the OP provides a picture of the rules that they have it can't be ruled out that they just got misread. As this question was asked over a year ago and the OP never responded to my question we can't really judge what the situation on the rules is.

Comment: @JoeW it was most likely the OP was playing the 2017 version of the rules, available here: https://instructions.hasbro.com/api/download/E4304_en-ca_the-game-of-life-game.pdf 
There have been no less than 5 rules changes around buying houses, not including the various themed version changes, and Hasbro seem to have left at least a few broken cards in each time they move to optional purchases

Comment: @KMR It sounds like you should post an answer on that, I had asked a question for clarification and it seems the op has abandoned the question.